# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in RelationshipsController#destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Hi I'm try to build an twitter like sample app .i have created a Relationship model ,In my view i have two forms one with follow button and another one with unfollow button in my view it looks like .

```
<% if current_user.following?(@otheruser) %>
     <%= render 'unfollow' %>
<% else %>
     <%= render 'follow' %>
 <% end %>
```

and I have in _follow.html.erb like

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, @otheruser.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

and in _unfollow.html.erb like

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @otheruser.id),
             html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
```

in my user.rb 
i have methods and associations like

```
has_many :active_relationships,  class_name:  "Relationship",
         foreign_key: "follower_id",
         dependent:   :destroy
has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
         foreign_key: "followed_id",
         dependent:   :destroy
has_many :following, through: :active_relationships,  source: :followed
has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower   

  def follow(other_user)
    active_relationships.create(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end
```

# Unfollows a user.

```
def unfollow(other_user)
   active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy
end
```

whenever i am clicking follow button it is creating a entry in relationship model in relationship.rb

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

but when i am clicking on unfollow button it is giving error as "Couldn't find Relationship with 'id'=" 
and can anyone help me to know how i can display user.followers and user.following thing.

in relationship controller is like

```
 class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @otheruser =  User.find_by_username(params[:name])
    @reviews  =  @otheruser.write_reviews.all
    @followers  = @otheruser.followers
  end
  def create
    user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(user)
    redirect_to followuser_url
  end
  def destroy
    user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(user)
    redirect_to followuser_url
  end
end
```

relationship table looks like

```
create_table "relationships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "follower_id", limit: 4
    t.integer  "followed_id", limit: 4
    t.datetime "created_at",            null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",            null: false
  end
```

Comment: lets see your controller

Comment: i have updated my question please refer.

Comment: which method is being called when unfollow btn is clicked

Comment: relationship#destroy

Comment: please any one can help...

Comment: can you please paste your params.

Comment: Anyone here to help ...

Answer (score 0):

I'll delete this if required, I just can't stand your code being all over the place:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   resources :relationships, path: "follow", only: [:create, :destroy]
end

#app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_user

   def create
      current_user.following << user
   end

   def destroy
      current_user.following.destroy(user)
   end

   private

   def set_user
       @user = User.find follow_params
   end

   def follow_params
      params.permit(:user_id)
   end
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :followers, class_name: "Relationship" #-> users following you
    has_many :following, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: :follower_id, association_foreign_key: :user_id #-> users you are following
end

#app/models/relationship.rb
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"

    validates :user, :follower, presence: true
    validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :follower_id }
end
```

--

This will allow you to use the following:

```
#app/views/relationships/_follow.html.erb
<% message = current_user.following?(user) ? "Unfollow" : "Follow" %>
<% method = current_user.following?(user) ? "method: :delete" : "" %>
<%= button_to message, user_relationship_path(user), eval(method), class: "btn btn-primary" %>

#app/views/users/index.html.erb
<% @users.each do |user| %>
   <%= render "relationships/follow", locals: { user: user } %>
<% end %>
```

The submission process will depend on sending the request to `url.com/users/5/follow` as either `POST` or `DELETE`.

At the controller-level, you'll be able to add or remove from the *following* relationship (`followers` will be other people's doing). This way, you don't need to set objects for `form_for` each time you want to create a new subscription.

---

Your tables can remain the same with the above code.

Comment: You could have just formatted the code in the question instead of pasting it all again.

Comment: Yeah I didn't paste it. I changed it all to be more efficient, which is why I mentioned I would delete the answer if in appropriate. I felt you could make a simpler implementation

Comment: you mean i need not to have _unfollow.html.erb instead i can render both in _follow.html.erb and instead of followed_id i should use user_id .

Comment: can you please explain in index.html.erb why u have used @user.each do

Comment: No I mean you can get rid of half the `form_for` references and `passive_relationship` etc.

Comment: I put it as an example

Comment: then how i can show user.followers and user.followings list

Comment: `<% user.followers.each %>` and `<% user.following.each %>`

Comment: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass,this is the error i am getting ,i have a doubt in index.html.erb you have written @users.each but '@'user is having only one record as in controller it is find by user_id which will return a single user record

Comment: Showing C:/Sites/pickyourchoice/app/views/relationships/_follow.html.erb where line #3 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"relationships", :id=>nil, :user_id=>#<User id: 7, email: "poojarathore.336@gmail.com",>} missing required keys: [:id]